# The adapter is not used

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using allauth 0.19.1. When I tried to use a custom adapter, nothing happens.
My config:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'account.adapters.CustomAccountAdapter'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'account.forms.SignupForm'
```

My adapter:

```
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        path = "/accounts/{username}/"
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

Also, I tried to use signals but result was the same

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def registered_user_login(sender, **kwargs):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    instance = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(kwargs['user'])
```

Comment: Is module alone working good? Have you finished installation http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html ?

Comment: Moved text out of code block; poster needs to add more of his settings to show that django knows to use allauth